# Getting commercial video DVD to play in Pi4b running Rasbian

Tags: dvd

I have a powdered USB 3.0 Hub running an external optical drive. The Pi can see the drive, and open all the files. In fact, when it offers to launch VLC automatically. However, nothing happens in VLC. You can hit play and the screen blinks and nothing happens. No error code. Just a black screen. Attempting to open disc from VLC does the same thing. My VLC is updated as of May 4th, 2020. I though all the needed codecs should be in VLC. Is there some kind of DRM blocking this? These are legitimately purchased video DVDs from a major retailer in the USA.

Comment: Try to open vlc in command line for showing any errors ? Also you can check the movie codec with [ffprobe](https://ffmpeg.org/ffprobe.html). You can check `/var/log/syslog` file also.

Comment: It's almost certainly some sort of DRM issue. The DVDs will open and show the menu but will not run the movie. The screen just goes black.

Comment: Yes probably. I can read this : 'Many Linux distributions (such as Debian, SuSE and Ubuntu) do not include libdvdcss in their official repositories. This is for fear of violating DMCA-type laws such as the European EUCD directive and its transcription into the law of the member states of the Union (DADVSI law in France). However libdvdcss is then often available in unofficial repositories.'

Comment: VLC libdvdcss [documentation](https://www.videolan.org/developers/libdvdcss/doc/html/)

Comment: Thanks. I found out it may be easier to simply rip the DVDs off the disc with something like Handbrake and then watch them off the micro-SD in the Pi than try to run them off the disc. I am going to try the libdvdcss though I've read conflicting information on that.

Answer (score 0):

I finally made some progress with this headache. Try "priming" your usb DVD Player. Plug it into Windows/A known good DVD playing computer and launch a DVD. I found a post that says some usb DVD players need to have the region code set at first launch. So once I played a DVD off my Windows laptop and plugged it back into my Pi, it worked like a charm! Only issue now is I have no video and choppy af audio :facepalm: